# Power Series Solution to $(\cos x)y'' + xy' - 2y = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I got the following question for some homework, and I am struggling with it. I know how to show they form a fundamental set of solutions and I have a guess at the radius of convergence. I am just struggling multiplying $\cos x$ by $y''$ and using that to find the first four nonzero terms in each of the two power series solutions about the origin.

> For $(\cos x)y'' + xy' - 2y = 0$, find the first four nonzero terms in each of two power series solutions about the origin. Show that they form a fundamental set of solutions. What do you expect the radius of convergence to be?

Comment: Use the Cauchy product for series

Comment: You have been asked to find only few terms!

Comment: I tried using the Cauchy product. The problem is I have no idea what to do with the result. Also, I need a recurrence relation for the first few terms.

Comment: See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232520/how-to-find-a-0-a-1-a-2-in-a-power-series-for-an-initial-value-problem/232668#232668) which is exactly the techniques you need.  I am not in a position that allow me to type alot!

Comment: I've solved it in a fashion I am familiar with! I will post an answer later if I am able to.

Comment: @Birdman2246: So why did you post a question? What you said in your post is that you had problem  multiplying $\cos x y''$!! Good luck!

Comment: I was having trouble using that result to find the first four terms in each solution, as said in the question.